# VBA Lookup function giving incorrect number on Error

Tags: excel, vba

I appreciate if you can help me on below code. I'm trying to do a lookup with the VBA Lookup function, and it gives an error 1004 when the looked up value isn't available in the table array. I have tried to use "On resume Resume Next" command to skip when result an error, but instead of skipping and giving a blank result, it throws the previous value on it.

```
Sub x()

Dim d As String

Set src = Range("A1:A5") 'list of names needs to be searched
Set Rng = Range("D1:E5") 'table array

On Error Resume Next

For Each cell In src

d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Rng, 2, 0)
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = d

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This `On Error Resume Next` just hides the error message but the error still occurs. It doesn't solve any problems it just tells VBA "If there is an error please don't show anyone". Never use that line without a complete error handling afterwards! You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the `Worksheetfunction` then a non-match will not throw a run-time error and you can instead test the return value using `IsError()`

```
Sub x()
    Dim src As Range, cell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim d as Variant  'not String, because it might need to
                      '  hold an error value if no match

    Set src = Range("A1:A5") 'list of names needs to be searched
    Set Rng = Range("D1:E5") 'table array

    For Each cell In src.Cells

        d = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, Rng, 2, 0)
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(d), "No Match", d)

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you skip an assignment which is causing an error in `d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Rng, 2, 0)`, the previous value hasn't been cleaned from the `d` variable.

You can try two approaches here:
1. Initialize the string in every iteration:

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In src
    d = vbNullString
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Rng, 2, 0)
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = d
Next cell
```

2. Skip assignment of string to cell, by defining a label, rather then `Resume Next`:

```
On Error Resume NextCell
For Each cell In src
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, Rng, 2, 0)
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = d
NextCell:
Next cell
```